# nested sortable not working(no drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

Here I have my list with 2 submenu. I don't understand why I can't do "drag and drop"
of any element of the list. I got this script in internet but I think I have done everything good.Maybe I don't see something very easy and sorry for that in advance!

```
       <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

    <style>
* {
    font-family: Arial;
}
span {
    cursor: move;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
   /* margin-bottom: -62px;*/
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #793D00;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 180px;
}
.highlighter {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: move;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px 14px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    background:#FFFF91;
}
ul {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 6;*/
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
li ul {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
li ul.ui-sortable {
    min-height: 60px;
    /*border: 1px solid #f00;*/
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 5;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.ui-sortable-helper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
ul.no-child {
    margin-bottom: -73px;   
}
</style>
<script>
$('ul').disableSelection().sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    cursorAt: {
        left: 40,
        top: 20
    },
    cursor: "move",
    opacity: 0.5,
    placeholder: "highlighter",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: 200,
    start: function(e, ui) { 
        if(ui.item.parent().hasClass("children-1")){
            ui.item.parent("ul").removeClass("child").addClass("no-child");
        }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) { 
        mkUl();
    }
});

function mkUl(){ 
    $("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("class");

        var ulLevel = $(this).parents('ul').length+1;
        $(this).addClass("ui-sortable no-child level_"+ulLevel);
        var childC = $(this).children("li").size(); 
        $(this).has("li").removeClass("no-child").addClass("child children-"+childC);

        $(this).children("li:first").addClass("first");
        $(this).children("li:last").addClass("last");
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    mkUl();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span><p>menu 1</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 1</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 2</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span><p>menu 2</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 1</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span><p>submenu 2</p>
                        <ul></ul>
                    </span> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the following section inside the document ready:

```
$('ul').disableSelection().sortable({
```

so that it becomes:

```
function mkUl(){ 
    $("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("class");

        var ulLevel = $(this).parents('ul').length+1;
        $(this).addClass("ui-sortable no-child level_"+ulLevel);
        var childC = $(this).children("li").size(); 
        $(this).has("li").removeClass("no-child").addClass("child children-"+childC);

        $(this).children("li:first").addClass("first");
        $(this).children("li:last").addClass("last");
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    mkUl();
    $('ul').disableSelection().sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        cursorAt: {
            left: 40,
            top: 20
        },
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.5,
        placeholder: "highlighter",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: 200,
        start: function(e, ui) { 
            if(ui.item.parent().hasClass("children-1")){
                ui.item.parent("ul").removeClass("child").addClass("no-child");
            }
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) { 
            mkUl();
        }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps